# AppStore Connect - Is IDFA gone?

Tags: app-store-connect, idfa

I'm uploading a new build of my iOS app and as always, I was going to check the IDFA options but I can't find them anywhere! Did something change?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 2):

It seems after requirement that apps use IDFA must ask users permission, Apple doesn't ask developers to select whether app use IDFA in App Store connect anymore.

So just submit app and don't care about it. I have submited an app successfully.

Comment: Ask permission how?

Comment: Ask permission with  AppTrackingTransparency framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency